# How to run an asynchronous task later in Python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-3.6, discord.py, python-asyncio

I am using discord.py async version and I need to assign a role 10.5 minutes after a user joins a server. I was considering using `threading.Timer(..)` but `member.add_roles(...)` is a coroutine and therefore `Timer` will not `await` it.

I tried an alternate method using `loop.call_later(...)` but in my testing I get a `RuntimeWarning` that my coroutine to add roles, `add_roles`, was never waiting. Here's what I tried so far:

```py
import discord, asyncio
from discord.utils import get

client = discord.Client()

async def on_member_join(member):
    ...
    newuser, noparty = get(member.guild.roles, name="New Member"), get(member.guild.roles, name="No Party")
    async def add_roles(member, newuser, noparty):
        await member.add_roles(newuser, noparty, reason="Auto-role new users.")
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.call_later(630, add_roles, member, newuser, noparty)
```

The expected outcome is that after 10.5 minutes the member will be assigned the `New User` and `No Party` roles, but instead I get the `RuntimeWarning` described above. My questions are: is this the proper approach? Or can I simply use `asyncio.sleep(630)` since the rest of my program is async functions? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await asyncio.sleep(630)`

Should work just fine.

If you have other things that you want to do inside `on_member_join` that you don't want to wait 10 minutes for, you could set it up to run it as an [asyncio task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object)

```py
async def give_permission_later(member, newuser, noparty):
    await asyncio.sleep(630)
    await member.add_roles(newuser, noparty, reason="Auto-role new users.")

async def on_member_join(member):
    ...
    newuser, noparty = get(member.guild.roles, name="New Member"), get(member.guild.roles, name="No Party")
    client.loop.create_task(give_permission_later(member, newuser, noparty))
    # More code that should execute now
```

Comment: Okay, since that's my last task I'll try that. Thanks!

Comment: To expand on that, calling `asyncio.sleep` is basically saying to the interpreter "come back to me in x amount of time", instead of normal `time.sleep`, which is basically "don't do anything else until x amount of time has passed"